# Are there any signals emitted when creating or opening a directory with QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory?

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I use something like:

```
CreateChooseDir() 
{ 

QString OpenedCreatedDirectory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Choose Directory"),
                                                              "/home",
                                                              QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);


    ui.PathLineEdit -> setText(OpenedDirectory);

    ui.PushButtonNext -> setEnable();
}
```

Problem here is, that I just want to set the `PushButtonNext` enabled if the `QFileDialog` was used to create or open a directory. At the moment the `PushButtonNext` is also enabled when just closing the `FileDialog`. So I thought of using an emitted signal if possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QFileDialog` inherits the `accepted` signal from `QDialog` - however, since you're using the static function `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory`, you won't have a chance to connect a signal.

Instead, simply check the returned `QString`: if the user clicks "Cancel", the string will be null (empty).

```
if(!OpenCreatedDirectory.isEmpty()) ui.PushButtonNext -> setEnable();
```